# ajax request fails when run on xampp, fine on mamp

Tags: ajax, xampp

I have a code igniter project that I run on Mamp on a macbook. I run an ajax request to localhost:xxxx/website/request which routes to a controller that receives post information to process the ajax request and responds with a json encoded array.

This works like a charm on Mamp, but when run on a windows localhost using Xampp, the ajax request fails. The controller still appears to be working as I can see the correct returned Json array but it is returned with a 500 internal server error header and the ajax fails.

I have tried altering the .htaccess as to another similar issue found online but that didnt seem to work, also checked the httpd.conf to check if mod_rewrite was loaded there and it was.

I am about to try running the Mamp for windows beta to see if that fixes the issue, but hope is low on that one but fingers crossed. The route of the error would still be nice to know even if it works.

This is incredibly frustrating so if anyone thinks they can help that would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

So it was painful, and it took a while, but i managed to fix it.

The error came from a destructor of one of the loaded models that called a save function which was not given a row id to save to. I am not sure of the reason that mamp on a mac was ok with it and xamp on windows had issues, i imagine either mamp is ignoring errors coming from the destructor or xampp is unnecesarily loading an instance of the object whereas mamp isnt bothering to.

It was down to some hastily written code on my part to be honest and it is better for me to write more robust code, but it was a pain.